# I have variable which asks for users input, how can i print that variable also using if/else in python?

Tags: python

This is my code:-

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input("Write a word")
if len(original)>0:
    print origninal
else:
    print "empty"
```

so here `original` is my variable. i get the string `"empty"` if user inputs no words, but if user inputs any words which is more than 0 characters (as defined in `if` statement) i am getting an error saying `"name original is not defined"`.
I want the console to print the users input. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Typo in error too, it must be `"name origninal is not defined"`.

Comment: To make it more pythonic, you could do `if original` instead of `len(original) > 0`

Comment: @ersran9 but i need to make sure the inout isnt empty!

Comment: Empty Strings evaluate to `False`, so there is no need for the `len` function.

Comment: This might be useful for you - http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. `origninal` should be `original`

```
if len(original) > 0:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

Comment: hey! that was stupidity! :/ n thanks anyway! :-p

Comment: @PavanNadig Haha, you're welcome :p. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)! Also, have fun learning python at codecademy :)

Comment: sure!.. i have to wait for 7 more min to accept the answer!!:p and i am amazed that you found out that its from cadecademy!? Just in curiosity how did u find that?
and one more question.. does 'typo' means error in spelling?

Comment: @PavanNadig: it's short for [typographical error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error).

Comment: @PavanNadig I learned python at Codecademy :)